# issue in dplyr: unwanted NA's in new column

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, na

I have the following data frame:

```
Xnumber   Number
X17339    EWY
X17339    LW2Y
X17401    EWC
X17401    LWY
X17466    EWC
X17466    LWY 
X17466    EWY
X17466    LWC
```

I want to create a new column, Number2, using the following code:

```
library(dplyr 
df3<-df3 %>% group_by(Xnumber) %>% mutate(Number2=if_else(lead(Number)=="LWC","Unknown",Number))
```

This is what I the resulting data frame should look like:

```
    Xnumber   Number   Number2
    X17339    EWY      EWY
    X17339    LW2Y     LW2Y
    X17401    EWC      EWC
    X17401    LWY      LWY
    X17466    EWC      EWC
    X17466    LWY      LWY
    X17466    EWY      Unknown
    X17466    LWC      LWC
```

But instead, I also get NA's in my new column, like this.

```
    Xnumber   Number   Number2
    X17339    EWY      EWY
    X17339    LW2Y     NA
    X17401    EWC      EWC
    X17401    LWY      NA
    X17466    EWC      EWC
    X17466    LWY      LWY
    X17466    EWY      Unknown
    X17466    LWC      NA
```

I'm not sure why this is happening. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why are you grouping the data? It doesn't seem like you actually want to take leads within groups. Maybe there's a case where you do, but it isn't in this data sample

Comment: That's a good point! I'm grouping the data for other parts of my analysis, so I did this automatically. Thanks for pointing this out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `default`:

```
library(dplyr)
 
df3<-df3 %>% 
  group_by(Xnumber) %>% 
  mutate(Number2=if_else(lead(Number, default = "") == "LWC","Unknown",Number))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you grouped your data, `lead` will return an NA at each group's end (no further in-group value ahead). If you want to replace these with, say, the most recent non-NA, {tidyr}'s `fill` comes in handy. Example:

```
data.frame(x = c(1:3, NA, 5)) |>
   tidyr::fill(x, .direction = 'down')
```